# how to use Estimote beacons on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, beacon, estimote

I can't make the func location  manager work on iOS  13, it  never gets called

```
           let nsuuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")
        if let clregion = nsuuid as UUID? {
            let constrain = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: clregion)
            let region =  CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: constrain, identifier: "Estimotes")
            self.locationManager.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constrain)
        }
    }
// Beacon tracking function
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
      didRange beacons: [CLBeacon],
    satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint){
        //get an array of beacon that are close
        var knownBeacons = beacons.filter { ($0.proximity == CLProximity.immediate) && ($0.accuracy > 0) }
```

in iOS 12 I used to do like this,

```
let nsuuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")
        if let clregion = nsuuid as UUID? {
            let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: clregion, identifier: "Estimotes")
            locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)

        }
    }

// Beacon tracking function
    ffunc locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
              didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], 
                           in region: CLBeaconRegion){
        //get an array of beacon that are close
        var knownBeacons = beacons.filter { ($0.proximity == CLProximity.immediate) && ($0.accuracy > 0) }
```

and it  worked just fine! 
Anyone can help me figure this ou, since the ios12 functions got deprecated

Comment: The code shown for iOS 12 should continue to work on iOS 13.   If it does not, please verify you have obtained location permission for your app on iOS 13.  The constructor `CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, identifier: "Estimotes")` has been deprecated in the iOS 13 SDK, but it still works.  It has a direct replacement that just renames the first parameter:  `CLBeaconRegion(uuid: uuid, identifier: "Estimotes")`  There is no reason to change your original code at all other than to remove a deprecation warning.

Comment: Thx for the answer,Tried it, but  the func location manager  still isn't being called, the code look  like this now::

 let nsuuid = NSUUID(uuidString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")
        if let clregion = nsuuid as UUID? {
            let region = CLBeaconRegion(uuid: clregion, identifier: "Estimotes")
            locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
            
        }
    }

Comment: I suggest you try an off-the-shelf beacon detector app like Locate Beacon and verify it detects your beacon properly.  You will need to configure the UUID into the app so iOS knows to look for it.  If that also fails, then your UUID may not be what you think it is.  A quick way to check that is to get an Android phone and run a detector app like Beacon Scope on that platform -- Android can detect beacons regardless of UUID>

Comment: I found what it was, i was trying to do it as a class, and it only works when you use it in the view controller, work like a charm now